# Instagram Api is not working in my server

Tags: api, instagram

I am developing an application using instagram Api. The app is working fine in test server. but when i changed it into clients server it is not. please help me. my php version 5.3. if instagram api needs any other reqiurement??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, his issue was likely due to not updating the application's url setting to the clients url.